# Android VoiceInteraction and Assist API

Tags: android, google-assist-api, voice-interaction

I've just read about the Android APIs called Assist and VoiceInteraction.
What I'm trying to achieve is an app like NowOnTap. For this, I need an access to the screen's content *before* the user long presses the home button.

First, I tried using a normal activity with the `android.intent.action.ASSIST` action.

Digging more into this, I found out that in order to access a screenshot before opening the apps, I need to implement `VoiceInteractionSession` and its methods `onCreateContentView` and `onHandleScreenshot`.

I wasn't able to create UI by using `onCreateContentView` and, according to my logs, it doesn't even gets called. Anyone with experience using this APIs?